# Baking a high poly object to low poly. Parts seem to have not been "baked"

Tags: baking

I have an issue when baking a high poly object onto a low poly object in Blender. The bake finishes although parts seem to have not been "baked"

See image attached - e.g. on the anvil horn the final result seems to have come out with lines on there, yet it is normally smooth? Also you can still see horizontal lines around the bottom of the object?

[image]

EDIT: Sorry I'm new to this - see below UV Image

[image]

EDIT: Yes I'm almost certain it was set to smooth shading. Could it possibly be because I "dented" the horn too much, meaning there was too much of a gap between the low poly and high poly meshes when baking? (see image below which hopefully explains what I mean)

[image]

Many thanks

Comment: you could add a Picture of your UV Map. That would maybe help us to figure out whats going on

Comment: Were all faces of the lowpoly set to smooth shading prior to baking?

Comment: I can see on the screenshot lines on the lowpoly mesh where its faces are. Make sure to enter Edit mode, select all and use W > Shade Smooth (or from the Toolshelf). Geometry there is too dense as well consisting likely of long thin faces which are often advised to be converted into more even faces

Comment: Thank you so much, I must not have set to smooth shading after all :/ Would you also mind explaining what you mentioned about converting into more faces?

Comment: just add more loop cuts so that your faces are more close to a square than a rectangle. Thats what MrZak means